# The 'BldgTypeID' property on 'Building' could not be set to a 'System.Int16

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am getting this error below, I don't know what is the reason that I got this error. It works fine two days ago. I started to get this error yesterday.

> Message = "The 'BldgTypeID' property on 'Building' could not be set to a 'System.Int16' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'System.Int32'. "

**Note**

The DataType of `BldgTypeID` when I get the error is in `smallint`

**Query**

```
var data = db.Buildings.Select(t=>t).Tolist();
```

**Database**

```
CREATE TABLE [REC].[Building](
    [BldgID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ActionID] [int] NULL,
    [TCTNo] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [BldgTypeID] [smallint] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Building] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [BldgID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I try to change the dataType from int into smallint vice versa. and still I got the same error. Even I update my EDMX.

Comment: if this is sql server may i ask you to add to your question the create table script

Comment: sorry for the late reply

Comment: I would have a look at the data type within the Building class that represents you database table. If you have updated the database from smallint to int I don't think its updated the class.

Comment: Try deleting model property of `BldgTypeID` from EDMX definition and re-add it using "Update Model from Database". Updating the table structure from SQL side might not immediately reflected in EDMX.

Comment: I notice in my EDMX > Building. the type of BldgTypeID is `int32`. I change it to `int16` and now its working.